# Using netcat/cat in a background shell script (How to avoid Stopped (tty input)? )

Tags: shell, input, background, tty, netcat

Abstract: How to run an interactive task in background?

Details: I am trying to run this simple script under ash shell (Busybox) as a background task.

> myscript.sh&

However the script stops immediately...

> [1]+  Stopped (tty input) myscript.sh

The myscript.sh contents... (only the relvant part, other then that I trap SIGINT, SIGHUP etc)

```
#!/bin/sh

catpid=0

START_COPY()
{
  cat /dev/charfile > /path/outfile &
  catpid = $! 
}

STOP_COPY()
{
  kill catpid 
}

netcat SOME_IP PORT | while read EVENT
do
  case $EVENT in
    start) START_COPY;;
    stop) STOP_COPY;;
  esac
done
```

From simple command line tests I found that bot cat and netcat try to read from tty.
Note that this netcat version does not have -e to supress tty.

Now what can be done to avoid myscript becoming stopped?

Things I have tried so for without any success:

1) netcat/cat ... < /dev/tty  (or the output of `tty`)

2) Running the block containing cat and netcat in a subshell using (). This may work but then how to grab PID of cat?

Over to you experts...

---

The problem still exists. 
A simple test for you all to try:

1) In one terminal run netcat -l -p 11111 (without &)

2) In another terminal run netcat localhost 11111 &  (This should stop after a while with message Stopped (TTY input) )

How to avoid this?

Comment: If you're fine with capturing input and output from a subprocess, you can use `script`. If that won't work, you might try researching [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html); it has advanced PTY handling, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to capture STDIN.

Comment: The illusatration is part of script which didn't work. socat is not the option for the environment I have (can't get it there).

Have tired to redirect /dev/ttyS0 to netcat and it seems to be working but then it stop receiving signals.

Comment: Is it feasible to restructure your program to use the Unix tool [`script`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script), with the `-f` option?

Answer (score 14):

you probably want `netcat's "-d" option`, which tells it not to read from `STDIN`.

Answer (score 9):

I can confirm that `-d` will help netcat run in the background.

I was seeing the same issue with:

```
nc -ulk 60001 | nc -lk 60002 &
```

Every time I queried the `jobs`, the pipe input would stop.

Changing the command to the following fixed it:

```
nc -ulkd 60001 | nc -lk 60002 &
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you've given your script as is or did you just type in a rough facsimile meant to illustrate the general idea?  The script in your question has many errors which should prevent it from ever running correctly, which makes me wonder.

1. The spaces around the `=` in `catpid=$!` make the line not a valid variable assignment.  If that was in your original script I am surprised you were not getting any errors.
2. The `kill catpid` line should fail because the literal word `catpid` is not a valid job id.  You probably want `kill "$catpid"`.

As for your actual question:

- `cat` should be reading from `/dev/charfile` and not from stdin or anywhere else.  Are you sure it was attempting to read tty input?
- Have you tried redirecting `netcat`'s input like `netcat < /dev/null` if you don't need `netcat` to read anything?

Comment: No, it was just an ilustration and as you pointed out there are typos. Anyway cat is actually reading from /dev/charfile (tested at command line). I just assumed that either netcat or cat is causing this Stopped (tty input) problem. Also tried /dev/null with netcat without success.

Answer (score 2):

I have to use a netcat that doesn't have the -d option.

"echo -n | netcat ... &" seems to be an effective workaround: i.e. close the standard input to netcat immediately if you don't need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As it was not yet really answered, if using Busybox and -d option is not available, the following command will keep netcat "alive" when sent to background:

```
tail -f /dev/null | netcat ...
```

`netcat < /dev/null` and `echo -n | netcat` did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Combining `screen` and `disown`-ing process work for me, as '-d' option is not a valid anymore for netcat. Tried redirecting like `nc </dev/null` but session ends prematurely (as I need -q 1 to make sure nc process stop as file transfer finished)

Setup Receiver side first,

> on Receiver side, screen keep stdin for netcat so it won't terminated

EDIT: I was wrong, you need to enter command INSIDE `screen`. You'll end with no file saved, or weird binary thing flow in your terminal while attach to `screen`, if you redirecting `nc` inline of `screen` command. (Example, this is THE WRONG WAY: <strike>`screen nc -l -p <listen port> -q 1 > /path/to/yourfile.bin`</strike>)

1. Open `screen` , then press `return/Enter` on welcome message. new blank shell will appear (you're inside screen now)
2. **type command:** `nc -l -p 1234 > /path/to/yourfile.bin`
3. then, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> , then press `d` to detach screen.

> on Sender sides, disown process, quit 1s after reaching EOF

```
cat /path/to/yourfile.bin | nc -q1 100.10.10.10 1234 & disown
```